# NetLogo - change color of patch when agent is on top

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make my turtle change the color of a patch when it comes into contact with it and have tried the following code:

```
to deesculateviolence
  ask turtles [
    if pcolor = red [set pcolor blue]
  ]
end
```

The code does not come up with any errors but when I play the model, the color of the patch does not change. I have tried similar codes from different models and still cannot get the patch to change color. If anyone knows where I am going wrong I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you. I've added the code to my model and it works well. I'm able to play with the code and build on from here. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code does the right thing :

```
to setup

  clear-all

  create-turtles 5 [
    move-to patch random 20 random 20

  ]
  ask n-of 25 patches [set pcolor red]
  reset-ticks
end

to go

  ask turtles [
  rt random 10
  fd 1

    if pcolor = red [set pcolor blue]
  ]
  tick
end
```

[image]

[image]

you can see the effect in following example better
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've edited this a little to avoid using `__clear-all-and-reset-ticks`, which exists only for backwards compatibility with old NetLogo versions. It should never be used in new code. Instead, put `clear-all` at the beginning of setup, and `reset-ticks` at the end.